# Why displayed picture is rotated left?

Tags: c#, winforms

I use winforms project.

I want display pictures made by mobile phone in picturebox control.
When I upload picture it rotated left 90 deg and showed 
inverted.

I don't do any rotations inside code.

Any idea why displayed pictures is rotated left?

Comment: It's an [EncoderParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter.-ctor), where a [Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.transformation) field has been applied. It's a common feature, to ease the presentation of Bitmaps in *rotating* devices. The Property Tag is `0x0112`.

Comment: It's usually because of the exif orientation tag.  When you view an image in Windows Photo Viewer, it automatically corrects image orientation if it has an Exif orientation data. `PictureBox` doesn't have built-in support for such functionality.  Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39247237/3110834) to see a custom picture box supporting that tag.